# Optimizing on R a code for a matrix which get the row/col names from a file and data values for other

Tags: r, matrix

Ok, so first I need to say sorry if I'm not very clear with the explanation because english is not my native language

For my studies I had to write a code to arrange the data from a txt file, a BLAST clustering output to be precise. The data was a file with:

```
##Gen_name_1; Gen_name_2; Identity_Percentage
```

Since the matches were for several genes, I had a Clustering_Output.txt file with ~89.000.000 rows with 3 columns. From there I did a file with just the genes names, called "Clean_names.txt", which had all the names without repeating them,in a file with ~94.000 gene names and 1 column.

As requested, the head of the data looks something like:
(used these random names I found because I have no access to the original file)

```
> head(gene_data)
       V1       V2      V3
1 EDGARDO  EDGARDO 100.000
2 EDGARDO    EDITH  96.482
3 EDGARDO  EDUARDO  97.911
4 EDGARDO EFR\x90N  99.040
5 EDGARDO    ELENA  95.690
6 EDGARDO    ELIAS  95.340

> head(list)
        V1
1  EDGARDO
2    EDITH
3  EDMUNDO
4  EDUARDO
5   EFRAIN
6 EFR\x90N

> head(name_list)
[1] "EDGARDO"  "EDITH"    "EDMUNDO"  "EDUARDO"  "EFRAIN"   "EFR\x90N"
```

I needed to create a matrix to send all this data to another program, and the prerequisites of that program are:

1. A square matrix,
2. Numbers are percentages from 0 to 1,
3. Only the diagonal can have "1"'s,
4. If there is no match, a "0" must be placed
5. It does not have row/col names

So, after hitting my head against a wall for a time, I did it on R, because I don't know much R .... but I know less of other computing language, and came out with this code.

I don't know if there is another way to do this, and searched on the internet to something similar, but found nothing this specific

```
    ##Read Files## 

    gene_data = read.table("Clustering_Output.txt", header = F, sep=";",dec=",",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    list = read.table("Clean_names.txt", header=F,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    name_list=as.character(list$V1)
    percentages=gene_data$V3
    print('File Load Ready')

    ##Get the lengths to create matrix##

    n=length(list$V1)
    t=length(gene_data$V1)
    print('Length vectors Ready')

    ##Create matrix##

    m=matrix(0, nrow=n, ncol=n)
    print('Matrix Created')

    ##Set matrix row/col names##

    colnames(m)=name_list[]
    rownames(m)=name_list[]
    print('Row/Col Names Assigned')

    ##Replace one by one the Identity from data into the matrix##

    for (i in 1:t){ 
      ##Read first data column##

      query=as.character(gene_data[i,1])
      ##Read second data column##

      hit=as.character(gene_data[i,2])

      ##Get identity percentage##
      identity=percentages[i]

      ##To just get 1's on the diagonal##
      if(isTRUE(query!=hit) && identity==100){      
        identity=99.99
      }

      ##Search row/column on the matrix##
      find_row=as.integer(match(hit, name_list))
      find_col=as.integer(match(query, name_list))

      ##Replace value##
      m[find_row,find_col]=(identity/100)

      ##Release some memory.... or something like that I read##
      gc()
    }

    print('Replacement Ready')
    ##Save to a file##

    from_count=1
    to_count=1 
    for(w in 1:n){
      to_count=from_count+1

    ##If n is not pair the save won't work, so I added an NA lines which can be easily deleted after##

        if(to_count>(n-1)){
          m=rbind(m,NA)
          write.table(m[from_count:to_count,], "Test2.txt", append=TRUE, col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, dec=",")
          break
        }

      ##Create the file and save 2 rows at a time##
      ##I don't know why saving 1 row saved it as a column, but 2 or more at a time worked fine##

      write.table(m[from_count:to_count,], "Test2.txt", append=TRUE, col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, dec=",")
      from_count=to_count+1
    }


    print ('Done :3')
```

The matrix I get looks like this

[Ending matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJV18.png)

The codes works fine on a small matrix but takes a lot of time in a big one like the one I have now. (used the 'bigmemory' package at first, but I could run the code without it, so removed that part)

My problem, and hence, the question is, I don't know any other way to handle a ~94.000 x 94.000 matrix without crashing the server we have here, but I don't know how long it will take, tested the code in a 11x11 matrix and took about 3 seconds, so a matrix that big will take .... I don't know, years? ...And yes, I forgot to put a counter inside the replacement part, so I don't know how long we'll have to wait, or how far the code has reached.
So now I'm trying to get a better version of this code in case I have to shut it down, but since my computing language is very limited I'd like ask for some help here.

Is there a way to improve this script? Maybe you can see something I'm missing, or you just know some more than I do.

Sorry if this is asked on another post, but searched the site and couldn't find it, and because I based my code on a lot of info I got from here I believe that here are the people that can improve it.

Comment: You'll get better feedback if you provide a few small example datasets, and the output you would expect from them. Most likely there is a much easier way to do what you're trying to do, and it's better to start with solving that problem than to first understand your code.

Try using `dput(head(dat))` so that the format of your data is clear.

Comment: done, thank you for the heads up

Comment: Is it possible for a given name pair to have more than one match? (ie, could there be more than one row where V1 = "Eduardo" and V2 = "Eduardo"?) And if so, what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Asked a little better, it can happen, but the file is chosen so just the max identity percentage is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said, it's tough without a small working test sample, but here's a try.

Generate some example data:

```
library(data.table)
library(gtools)

#Generate some test data
name_list <- c("EDGARDO", "EDITH", "EDMUNDO", 
               "EDUARDO", "EFRAIN", "EFR\x90N")
dat <- data.table(permutations(length(name_list), 
                               2, 
                               name_list, 
                               repeats.allowed = TRUE))
dat[, V3 := runif(dim(dat)[1], 0, 1)]
dat[V1 == V2, V3 := 1]

# Now, like your example, lets add a gene that doesn't have values against other genes
dat <- rbind(dat, data.table(V1 = "NEWGENE", V2 = "NEWGENE", V3 = 1))
dat
```

Results in dataset:

```
         V1      V2         V3
 1: EDGARDO EDGARDO 1.00000000
 2: EDGARDO   EDITH 0.52602966
 3: EDGARDO EDMUNDO 0.22507335
 4: EDGARDO EDUARDO 0.48641176
 5: EDGARDO   EFRN 0.37021480
 6: EDGARDO  EFRAIN 0.98335018
 7:   EDITH EDGARDO 0.38831912
 8:   EDITH   EDITH 1.00000000
 9:   EDITH EDMUNDO 0.62329755
10:   EDITH EDUARDO 0.13654020
11:   EDITH   EFRN 0.96746949
12:   EDITH  EFRAIN 0.51507181
13: EDMUNDO EDGARDO 0.16307033
14: EDMUNDO   EDITH 0.62190230
15: EDMUNDO EDMUNDO 1.00000000
16: EDMUNDO EDUARDO 0.66877152
17: EDMUNDO   EFRN 0.41891590
18: EDMUNDO  EFRAIN 0.32334499
19: EDUARDO EDGARDO 0.83525532
20: EDUARDO   EDITH 0.14381704
21: EDUARDO EDMUNDO 0.19281595
22: EDUARDO EDUARDO 1.00000000
23: EDUARDO   EFRN 0.30811955
24: EDUARDO  EFRAIN 0.36330054
25:   EFRN EDGARDO 0.78394648
26:   EFRN   EDITH 0.19337868
27:   EFRN EDMUNDO 0.01776581
28:   EFRN EDUARDO 0.40660787
29:   EFRN   EFRN 1.00000000
30:   EFRN  EFRAIN 0.42184495
31:  EFRAIN EDGARDO 0.34280880
32:  EFRAIN   EDITH 0.86648331
33:  EFRAIN EDMUNDO 0.45510805
34:  EFRAIN EDUARDO 0.53376487
35:  EFRAIN   EFRN 0.96384333
36:  EFRAIN  EFRAIN 1.00000000
37: NEWGENE NEWGENE 1.00000000
```

You can then make this a wide table using `dcast`.

`dat2 <- dcast(dat, V1 ~ V2, value.var = "V3", drop = FALSE, fill = 0)`

```
        V1   EDGARDO     EDITH    EDMUNDO   EDUARDO    EFRAIN     EFRN NEWGENE
1: EDGARDO 1.0000000 0.5260297 0.22507335 0.4864118 0.9833502 0.3702148       0
2:   EDITH 0.3883191 1.0000000 0.62329755 0.1365402 0.5150718 0.9674695       0
3: EDMUNDO 0.1630703 0.6219023 1.00000000 0.6687715 0.3233450 0.4189159       0
4: EDUARDO 0.8352553 0.1438170 0.19281595 1.0000000 0.3633005 0.3081196       0
5:  EFRAIN 0.3428088 0.8664833 0.45510805 0.5337649 1.0000000 0.9638433       0
6:   EFRN 0.7839465 0.1933787 0.01776581 0.4066079 0.4218450 1.0000000       0
7: NEWGENE 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000       1
```

This is likely much faster than building the matrix by hand. If you need it in matrix format:

`as.matrix(dat2[, !"V1"])`

```
       EDGARDO     EDITH    EDMUNDO   EDUARDO    EFRAIN     EFRN NEWGENE
[1,] 1.0000000 0.5260297 0.22507335 0.4864118 0.9833502 0.3702148       0
[2,] 0.3883191 1.0000000 0.62329755 0.1365402 0.5150718 0.9674695       0
[3,] 0.1630703 0.6219023 1.00000000 0.6687715 0.3233450 0.4189159       0
[4,] 0.8352553 0.1438170 0.19281595 1.0000000 0.3633005 0.3081196       0
[5,] 0.3428088 0.8664833 0.45510805 0.5337649 1.0000000 0.9638433       0
[6,] 0.7839465 0.1933787 0.01776581 0.4066079 0.4218450 1.0000000       0
[7,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000       1
```

You can write dat2 to file:

```
write.table(dat2,
            file = "dat.csv",
            sep = ",",
            quote = FALSE,
            row.names = FALSE)
```

Or, if you're going to use it in R, `saveRDS(dat2, "dat2.rds")`.

Comment: thank you so much, it made it a lot faster without the creation/modification steps, the only problem is that "> as.matrix(dat2[,!"V1"])" gives me the error
 "Error in !"V1" : invalid argument type", .... which I get what you are trying to do, but I'd do a "as.matrix(dat2[,2:nrow(dat2)])" unless suggested otherwise

Comment: You probably have an older version of `data.table`, I think the `dat2[, !"V1"]` syntax is new.  Note that I'm dropping the first column, so 2:ncol would be more robust than 2:nrow, if for some reason it wasn't a square.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I meant that, or maybe 2:(nrow(dat2)+1), but yeah, again, thank a lot

Comment: I have to ask, anything on the "save to a file" part, or it should be fine with a file of that size?

Comment: You can write dat2 to file using `write.table` or `saveRDS`, updated the answer to include.

Comment: thank you, but I believe that won't work, the dat2 matrix it's too big to get exported directly and returns me an error, or so it did before with a [n x n] matrix filled with "0"

Comment: Ah, right, you're 94k x 94k. How big is it in memory? Saving as a .rds file will have the benefit of the file size being much smaller than a .csv.  

I just tried a 90k x 9k matrix of zeros and it's 6 GB in memory. Ouch. So about 60 GB for the full thing. 

In general, there isn't going to be a way to get around that. Is there anyway you can reduce the dimensionality of your problem? Remove genes that have no correlation, or sample randomly from the data?

Comment: Yeah, it's about 60~70 GB , they said that the size doesn't matter, it just have to be done with that file, and the file is already reduced, there are only genes with over 95% correlation.

The code worked fine, but the saving part got me an error ..... put a little print %  inside the loop, and throw me an "out of bounds error" at 26% .... maybe there is a name there that doesn't match the rest